# change appendix name when using autoref

Tags: babel, appendix, autoref

Whenever I use `\autoref{sec:anexo1}`, it displays 'Apêndice'. However, I want it to display 'Anexo', because the document uses Portuguese as main language and the word Anexo suits better than Apêndice for what I am doing. The issue here is not with the toc or with the sections of the appendix. I just want `autoref` to write *Anexo* instead of *Apêndice*. I have tried many solutions, unsuccessful, such as

```
\addto\captionsportuguese{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
}.
```

More details about the used syntax:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
% [...]

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\section{ANEXO I -- blablabla \label{sec:anexo1}}
This is \autoref{sec:anexo1}. % here it displays Apêndice I and I want Anexo I.
\section{ANEXO II -- blablabla \label{sec:anexo2}}
This is \autoref{sec:anexo2}. % here it displays Apêndice II and I want Anexo II.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it burried in the hyperref code.  The name is stored in the aux file as `appendix`, but autoref uses `\csname #1autorefname\endcsname` to translate.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\AtBeginDocument{\def\appendixautorefname{Anexo}}
\addto\extrasportuguese{\def\appendixautorefname{Anexo}}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\section{ANEXO I -- blablabla \label{sec:anexo1}}
This is \autoref{sec:anexo1}. % here it displays Apêndice I and I want Anexo I.
\section{ANEXO II -- blablabla \label{sec:anexo2}}
This is \autoref{sec:anexo2}. % here it displays Apêndice II and I want Anexo II.
\end{document}
```

Comment: better use the babel interface `\addto\extrasportuguese{\def\appendixautorefname{Anexo}}`.

Comment: Thank you John Kormylo and @UlrikeFischer! Both solutions worked like a charm. I was really confused if the code would concern hyperref, babel or something else.